# Enter Key Not Consumed by MessageBox, C#, Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a custom control on it.  Assume the custom
control has the focus.  If I show a message box from that form,
when the message box is closed by pressing Enter on either the
OK or Cancel button, the message box is closed and then the
custom control gets a keyboard event (OnKeyUp) with the enter
key.

This doesn't happen if the space key is used to "press" either
the OK or Cancel button.

It's like the MessageBox doesn't consume the Enter Key for 
some reason. I tried this with the Form's KeyPreview property
turned on, but there was no difference.

Does anyone know how to stop that enter message after it is
used to press the MessageBox button?

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  Yes, I could ignore it but most of the time I need that event.

The solution turned out to be using OnKeyDown or OnKeyPressed instead of OnKeyUp, as the former two events ARE consumed by the message box.

Comment: Please post this as an answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the answers. Yes, I could ignore it but most of the time I need that event. The solution turned out to be using OnKeyDown or OnKeyPressed instead of OnKeyUp, as the former two events ARE consumed by the message box.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you ignore it in code?
This is VB syntax:

```
    Private Sub frmEdit_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done a rough conversion from VB.NET to C# for you, I hope this helps.

```
private void frmEdit_KeyUp(ByVal object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if( e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
      {
         e.Handled = true;
      }
   else Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyDown event instead. that will not cause this problem.